# how to call a jquery click function by a button generated from ajax file

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

hi i have a form which appends a table when a user inputs a value for eg. if a user inputs '1' then the values related to '1' will be appended on a table and the table will be appended on my page but i am even calling a function of jquery which will append a table row when add button is pressed but the function is not working is it because i am generating the button by ajax???? can anyone help me in this

here is my script to generate a new row

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
          var currentItem = $('#items').val();
                $('#addnew').click(function() {
          var strToAdd = '<tr><td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="6" id="ord_' + currentItem + '" maxlength="6" name="ord_' + currentItem + '" class="form-input-oth" onkeyup="return copy(this.val());"/></td>\n\
                                        <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="6" id="srno' + currentItem + '" maxlength="6" name="srno_' + currentItem + '" class="form-input-oth"/></td>\n\
                                        <td align="center"><textarea name="descrip_' + currentItem + '" id="descrip_' + currentItem + '" cols="70" class="form-input-textarea"></textarea></td>\n\
                                        <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="9" id="unit_' + currentItem + '" maxlength="6" name="unit_' + currentItem + '" class="form-input-rate"/></td>\n\
                                        <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="9" id="rate_' + currentItem + '" maxlength="6" name="rate_' + currentItem + '" class="form-input-rate"/></td></tr>';
                     $('#data').append(strToAdd);
                       currentItem++;
                       $('#items').val(currentItem);

                });
            });
```

here is my textbox from which i am calling the ajax function

```
<input type="text" size="6" maxlength="6" id="code" maxlength="6" name="quotno" value="<?php echo ($addflag == 0) ? $get['quotno'] : ""; ?>" class="form-input-code"  onblur="showyear('boqsrch.php?code='+this.value);"/>
```

here is my file from which the table is generated

```
<?php
require("includes/dbconnect.php");
include ('includes/function.php');

$code = trim($_GET["code"]);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM quotdtl WHERE vouchno='$code'") or die(mysql_error());

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    echo '<div style="margin-left: 400px; margin-right: auto;  width:180px;">
            <h2><font color="#0099FF"  face="Times New Roman">Bill Of Quotation</font></h2>
          </div>
          <hr/>
          ';
    echo "<table border=\"1px\" width=\"80%\" id=\"data\" align=\"center\">";
;?>

                  <tr>
                     <td width="130px" align="center"><label for=""><font color="#0099FF" size="3px">Order</font><span></span></label></td>
                     <td width="130px" align="center"><label for=""><font color="#0099FF" size="3px">Sr No.</font><span></span></label></td>
                     <td width="580px" align="center"><label for=""><font color="#0099FF" size="3px">Description</font><span></span></label></td>
                     <td width="130px" align="center"><label for=""><font color="#0099FF" size="3px">Unit</font><span></span></label></td>
                     <td width="130px" align="center"><label for=""><font color="#0099FF" size="3px">Rate</font><span></span></label></td>
                  </tr>

<?php

    $ctr = 0;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td align=\"center\"><input type=\"text\" size=\"6\" maxlength=\"6\" id=\"ord_$ctr\" maxlength=\"6\" name=\"ord_$ctr\" value=\"$row[orderby]\" class=\"form-input-oth\" onkeyup=\"document.getElementById('ord_$ctr').value = this.value;\"/></td>";
        echo "<td align=\"center\"><input type=\"h\" size=\"6\" maxlength=\"6\" id=\"srno_$ctr\" maxlength=\"6\" name=\"srno_$ctr\" value=\"$row[srno]\" class=\"form-input-oth\" onkeyup=\"document.getElementById('srno_$ctr').value = this.value;\"/></td>";
        echo "<td align=\"center\"><textarea name=\"descrip_$ctr\" cols=\"70\" class=\"form-input-textarea\" onkeyup=\"document.getElementById('descrip_$ctr').value = this.value;\">$row[descrip]</textarea></td>";
        echo "<td align=\"center\"><input type=\"text\" size=\"6\" maxlength=\"9\" id=\"unit_$ctr\" maxlength=\"6\" name=\"unit_$ctr\" value=\"$row[unit]\" class=\"form-input-rate\" onkeyup=\"document.getElementById('unit_$ctr').value = this.value;\"/></td> ";
        echo "<td align=\"center\"><input type=\"text\" size=\"6\" maxlength=\"9\" id=\"rate_$ctr\" maxlength=\"6\" name=\"rate_$ctr\" value=\"$row[rate]\" class=\"form-input-rate\" onkeyup=\"document.getElementById('rate_$ctr').value = this.value;\"/></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        $ctr++;
    }
    echo '</table>';

} else {
    ?>
            <div style="margin-left: 400px; margin-right: auto;  width:180px;">
                <h2><font color="#0099FF"  face="Times New Roman">Bill Of Quotation</font></h2>
            </div>
            <hr/>
                 <table border="1px" width="80%" id="data" align="center">
                  <tr>
                      <td><br /></td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                     <td width="130px" align="center"><label for=""><font color="#0099FF" size="3px">Order</font><span></span></label></td>
                     <td width="130px" align="center"><label for=""><font color="#0099FF" size="3px">Sr No.</font><span></span></label></td>
                     <td width="580px" align="center"><label for=""><font color="#0099FF" size="3px">Description</font><span></span></label></td>
                     <td width="130px" align="center"><label for=""><font color="#0099FF" size="3px">Unit</font><span></span></label></td>
                     <td width="130px" align="center"><label for=""><font color="#0099FF" size="3px">Rate</font><span></span></label></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="6" id="ord_0" maxlength="6" name="ord_0" value="" class="form-input-oth" onkeyup="document.getElementById('ord_0').value = this.value;"/></td> 
                    <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="6" id="srno_0" maxlength="6" name="srno_0" value="" class="form-input-oth" onkeyup="document.getElementById('srno_0').value = this.value;"  /></td> 
                    <td align="center"><textarea name="descrip_0" cols="20" class="form-input-textarea" onkeyup="document.getElementById('descrip_0').value = this.value;"></textarea></td>
                    <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="9" id="unit_0" maxlength="6" name="unit_0" value="" class="form-input-rate" onkeyup="document.getElementById('unit_0').value = this.value;"  /></td> 
                    <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="9" id="rate_0" maxlength="6" name="rate_0" value="" class="form-input-rate" onkeyup="document.getElementById('rate_0').value = this.value;"  /></td> 
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="6" id="code" maxlength="6" name="ord_1" value="" class="form-input-oth" onkeyup="document.getElementById('ord_1').value = this.value;"  /></td> 
                    <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="6" id="code" maxlength="6" name="srno_1" value="" class="form-input-oth" onkeyup="document.getElementById('srno_1').value = this.value;"  /></td> 
                    <td align="center"><textarea name="descrip_1" cols="20" class="form-input-textarea" onkeyup="document.getElementById('descrip_1').value = this.value;"></textarea></td>
                    <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="9" id="code" maxlength="6" name="unit_1" value="" class="form-input-rate" onkeyup="document.getElementById('unit_1').value = this.value;"  /></td> 
                    <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="9" id="code" maxlength="6" name="rate_1" value="" class="form-input-rate" onkeyup="document.getElementById('rate_1').value = this.value;"  /></td> 
                  </tr>
                   <tr>
                    <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="6" id="code" maxlength="6" name="ord_2" value="" class="form-input-oth" onkeyup="document.getElementById('ord_2').value = this.value;"  /></td> 
                    <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="6" id="code" maxlength="6" name="srno_2" value="" class="form-input-oth" onkeyup="document.getElementById('srno_2').value = this.value;"  /></td> 
                    <td align="center"><textarea name="descrip_2" cols="20" class="form-input-textarea" onkeyup="document.getElementById('descrip_2').value = this.value;"/></textarea></td>
                    <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="9" id="code" maxlength="6" name="unit_2" value="" class="form-input-rate" onkeyup="document.getElementById('unit_2').value = this.value;"  /></td> 
                    <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="9" id="code" maxlength="6" name="rate_2" value="" class="form-input-rate" onkeyup="document.getElementById('rate_2').value = this.value;" /></td> 
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="6" id="code" maxlength="6" name="ord_3" value="" class="form-input-oth" onkeyup="document.getElementById('ord_3').value = this.value;"/></td> 
                    <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="6" id="code" maxlength="6" name="srno_3" value="" class="form-input-oth" onkeyup="document.getElementById('srno_3').value = this.value;" /></td> 
                    <td align="center"><textarea name="descrip_3" cols="20" class="form-input-textarea" onkeyup="document.getElementById('descrip_3').value = this.value;"></textarea></td>
                    <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="9" id="code" maxlength="6" name="unit_3" value="" class="form-input-rate" onkeyup="document.getElementById('unit_3').value = this.value;"/></td> 
                    <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="9" id="code" maxlength="6" name="rate_3" value="" class="form-input-rate" onkeyup="document.getElementById('rate_3').value = this.value;"/></td> 
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="6" id="code" maxlength="6" name="ord_4" value="" class="form-input-oth"  onkeyup="document.getElementById('ord_4').value = this.value;"/></td> 
                    <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="6" id="code" maxlength="6" name="srno_4" value="" class="form-input-oth"  onkeyup="document.getElementById('srno_4').value = this.value;" /></td> 
                    <td align="center"><textarea name="descrip_4" cols="20" class="form-input-textarea" onkeyup="document.getElementById('descrip_4').value = this.value;"></textarea></td>
                    <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="9" id="code" maxlength="6" name="unit_4" value="" class="form-input-rate" onkeyup="document.getElementById('unit_4').value = this.value;"/></td> 
                    <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="9" id="code" maxlength="6" name="rate_4" value="" class="form-input-rate" onkeyup="document.getElementById('rate_4').value = this.value;"  /></td> 
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="6" id="code" maxlength="6" name="ord_5" value="" class="form-input-oth" onkeyup="document.getElementById('ord_5').value = this.value;"/></td> 
                    <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="6" id="code" maxlength="6" name="srno_5" value="" class="form-input-oth" onkeyup="document.getElementById('srno_5').value = this.value;"  /></td> 
                    <td align="center"><textarea name="descrip_5" cols="20" class="form-input-textarea" onkeyup="document.getElementById('descrip_5').value = this.value;"></textarea></td>
                    <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="9" id="code" maxlength="6" name="unit_5" value="" class="form-input-rate" onkeyup="document.getElementById('unit_5').value = this.value;"/></td> 
                    <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="9" id="code" maxlength="6" name="rate_5" value="" class="form-input-rate" onkeyup="document.getElementById('rate_5').value = this.value;"/></td> 
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="6" id="code" maxlength="6" name="ord_6" value="" class="form-input-oth" onkeyup="document.getElementById('ord_6').value = this.value;"/></td> 
                    <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="6" id="code" maxlength="6" name="srno_6" value="" class="form-input-oth" onkeyup="document.getElementById('srno_6').value = this.value;"/></td> 
                    <td align="center"><textarea name="descrip_6" cols="20" class="form-input-textarea" onkeyup="document.getElementById('descrip_6').value = this.value;"></textarea></td>
                    <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="9" id="code" maxlength="6" name="unit_6" value="" class="form-input-rate"  onkeyup="document.getElementById('unit_6').value = this.value;" /></td> 
                    <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="9" id="code" maxlength="6" name="rate_6" value="" class="form-input-rate"  onkeyup="document.getElementById('rate_6').value = this.value;" /></td> 
                  </tr>
                  <?php }?>
            </table>

                         &nbsp;<input type="button" id="addnew" class="addnew" class="classname" name="addnew" value="+" /> 
                          <input type="hidden" id="items" name="items" value="7" />
```

Comment: [`MySQL`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) (`mysql_*` functions) extension is [***deprecated***](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php). I suggest to use [`MySQLi`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (`mysqli_*` functions) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead. Your code also is vulnurable to [***SQL-Injection***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: yes i will but can u suggest me any solution for my problem ?

Comment: You need to use .ON() JQuery function : `$('body').on('click','#addnew',(function() {});`

Comment: Sounds like you need [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/), provided you're on jQuery 1.7+

Comment: but the $('body').on('click','#addnew',(function() {}); is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the following:

```
// New way (jQuery 1.7+) - .on(events, selector, handler)
$('#container').on('click', '#inputButtonID', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('testlink'); 
});
```

This will attach your event to any input within the `#container` element, 
reducing the scope of having to check the whole `document` element tree and increasing efficiency.

More info here:

- http://api.jquery.com/on/
- http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: Try this --> `$(document).on('click', '#addnew', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('testlink'); 
});`

Comment: This should work! I guess, the issue is somewhere else in your code.

Comment: See this [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/qtRGB/). This works for elements created dynamically...

Comment: yeah even i am thinking that sir if u could find any error for it would be a huge favor

Comment: sir i tried that the code from your demo in mine but even thats not working

Comment: Is the demo on the fiddle site working for you? Have you include the required jQuery v1.9.1 file in your code? Please check!

Comment: i have included this file --><script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

Comment: Yes, seem like your script tag is not correct. Comment it out and use this instead `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>`. Everything will work fine!

Comment: Ok, just create a new page and paste this `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>p { color:red; }</style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
  $("p").text("The DOM is now loaded and can be manipulated.");
});
  </script>
 
</head>
<body>
  <p>Not loaded yet.</p>
 
</body>
</html>`. See what you are getting on the page??? Is it **The DOM is now loaded and can be manipulated.** in red color???

Answer (score 1):

Try binding the click event using `on` instead of `click` http://api.jquery.com/on/

This will allow the behavior to work on any event matching the selector even ones that came to be after the binding takes place.